# Proving the contradiction between these two statements

Tags: proof-explanation

Suppose that

$$\sqrt{2}+1 = \frac{m}{n}$$

where $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers with $m$ as small as possible. Deduce that we also have 
$$\sqrt{2}+1 = \frac{n}{m−2n}$$

This is a contradiction. Why?

Comment: For the last step: Clearly, $\sqrt 2+1>1$, hence $m>n$ and we have a contradiction to theminimality of $m$

Comment: do you mean $$\sqrt{2}+1=\frac{m}{n}$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes that's what i mean

Comment: @Dylan i deduced the second equation but can't find the contradiction

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Observe that

$$\sqrt {2}+1=\frac {1}{\sqrt {2}-1}$$